# angularjs validation in a form

Tags: angularjs, html

HI all i am  new in angularjs please someone tell where i am wrong with this code my html is here :

```
<div class="form">
   <div id="signup">
      <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
      <form action="/" name="loginForm" method="post" ng-submit="sendLoginData()>
         <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="email"required autocomplete="off" name="userEmail" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
            <p ng-show="loginForm.userEmail.$error.required">Please Enter  Your E-mail</p>
         </div>
         <div class="field-wrap">
            <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name="userPassword" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <p ng-show="loginForm.userPassword.$error.required">Please Enter Your Password</p>
         </div>
         <span class="forgot"><a href ="#sign-up">Sign up</a></span>
         <p class="forgot"><a href="#forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a></p>
         <input type="submit" class="button button-block" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" value="Log IN"/>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please describe ur problem with this code

Comment: You two fields have 'required' in them twice. Also some spacing issues such as (type="email"required).

Comment: You have syntax error near ng-submit="sendLoginData() you forgot closing branket **ng-submit="sendLoginData()"**

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with this

```
<div class="form">
       <div id="signup">
          <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
          <form action="/" name="loginForm" method="post" ng-submit="sendLoginData()">
             <div class="field-wrap">
                <input type="email"required autocomplete="off" name="userEmail" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
                <p ng-show="loginForm.userEmail.$touched && loginForm.userEmail.$error.required">Please Enter  Your E-mail</p>
             </div>
             <div class="field-wrap">
                <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" name="userPassword" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" required/>
                <p ng-show="loginForm.userPassword.$touched && loginForm.userPassword.$error.required">Please Enter Your Password</p>
             </div>
             <span class="forgot"><a href ="#sign-up">Sign up</a></span>
             <p class="forgot"><a href="#forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a></p>
             <input type="submit" class="button button-block" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" value="Log IN"/>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
```